# How can I select group Name and count of FeedPost

Tags: api, chatter, c#

I want to get (select) VersionData field of ContentVersion Table with C#. It is possible?
I can select the other fields in the table, but I failed to select VersionData.

There is a blocking of salesforce on this field?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Pecheur, welcome to SFSE!  It would be helpful if you could include a (short, focused) code sample demonstrating what you've tried and highlighting what doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should be able to select this field. **Please post the code**! The following should be noted anyhow:

**1.** This field is encoded in base64. 
**2.** The maximum file size you can upload via the SOAP API must be less than 50 MB. 
**3.** When a document is uploaded or downloaded via the API, it is converted to base64 and stored in VersionData. This conversion increases the document size by approximately 37%.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.

I resolved my problem :) but I have one problem: the binding.query("...") return always one record but in the database I have many records of ContentVersion.

Thank you for your help

my code:

```
            SforceService binding = new SforceService();
            LoginResult loginResult = binding.login("username", "password");
            binding.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;

            binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
            binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;

            QueryResult qr = null;
            binding.QueryOptionsValue = new sforce.QueryOptions();

            //binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 250;
            //binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = true;

            qr = binding.query("select Id, ContentDocumentId,  ContentUrl,  PathOnClient, FileType,  VersionData, ContentSize  from ContentVersion limit 100");

            sObject[] records = qr.records;
            ContentVersion _contentVersion = null;
            string _pathAndFileName = "";
            int __nbrDocFailed = 0;

            foreach (sObject _obj in records)
            {
                 _contentVersion = (ContentVersion)_obj;
                try
                {
                    _pathAndFileName = Settings.Default.VersionDataDirectory + _contentVersion.PathOnClient.Substring(_contentVersion.PathOnClient.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(@"" + _pathAndFileName, _contentVersion.VersionData);
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    __nbrDocFailed ++;
                }
            }
```